# Custom dynamic version provider for Python projects

Tags: python, setuptools, build-system, pyproject.toml

In a Python project that uses pyproject.toml (and setuptools), I want to have a custom version number provider. I want it to work like `setuptools_scm`, but use my own logic to determine the version (and preferably other fields such as description and author). I know it can be accomplished by using dynamic metadata, but I would like it to work just by including the module in `[build-system]`. How do I do that? How does `setuptools` knows where to get the metadata from?

Comment: "*How does setuptools knows where to get the metadata from?*" It doesn't. You tell it. You put `version` field into `setup.py` or `pyproject.toml`. `setuptools_scm` get the version from SCM (read: Git), from the current tag.

Comment: Of course, but how does setuptools knows to call setuptools_scm? I want to replace the latter with a module of my own

Comment: You might need to read `setuptools-scm`'s code (unless it is explained in the documentation somewhere). -- Maybe this: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/extension.html#customizing-distribution-options